# Serving a Create-React-App application with a Node/Express router module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I'm fairly new to CRA, and normally I just use regular React with Webpack. I'm trying to serve my CRA just like I would any other React apps. My root directory file structure currently looks something like this:

```
controllers/
build/
app.js
package.json
```

Where "app.js" is my Node/Express server, `build/` is the build folder for my CRA application (the index.hmtl, static directory, manifest, etc. are all here), and `controllers/` is my router files. The router file I have to serve my react, called "staticController.js", is in the controllers/ directory and looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/client/static/home", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, ".." , "/build/index.html"));
})

module.exports = router;
```

I import this router module into app.js to use it, and run the router on port 3001. When I go to localhost:3001/client/static/home, I get a blank page and an error saying:

> GET http://localhost:3001/static/css/1.1ee5c864.chunk.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I'm not sure how to specifiy to CRA that the static directory and all associated build files should be under the "build/" directory. So instead, I move the static folder outside the build directory, into the root directory. The file structure looks like this now:

```
controllers/
build/
static/
app.js
package.json
```

When I try the route again, I still get the same error. Now I'm a bit confused as to how Node file structure works. If app.js is in the root directory, wouldn't localhost:3001/static/ just be my `static/` folder? Why can't the CRA app find this folder?

Answer (score 1):

use

> **express.static**

to serve the build folder (or any static files)

e.g. : here i'm serving the build folder on the root path (assuming it's located on the same directory as the server file)

```
app.use('/', express.static('build'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `static`.

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static

You need something like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('static'));
```